# Probability Tree-diagram with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-trees, trees

Thanks for helping me out.

How can I make the following tree-diagrams?

http://www.vias.org/tmdatanaleng/cc_prob_cond_independ.html

Comment: See also this related question, [Probability tree using TikZ for Bernoulli experiments?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19855/probability-tree-using-tikz-for-bernoulli-experiments).

Answer (score 10):

There is a nice example of a [probability tree](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/probability-tree/) on [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net). That might help you get started.

Comment: Isn't this more of a comment than an answer?

Comment: @Svend Well, I though it was an answer (albeit short) but I see no problem if a mod convert it to a comment.

Comment: I'm not saying that is a comment; I'm just asking. `:)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Is it, however, objectionable on the grounds that it is a link-only answer?

Answer (score 8):

A `forest` solution though there are better versions around if you search, I think. This is not exactly like the image you linked to because that one seems rather ugly to me. Obviously, you can adjust this if you prefer greater ugliness.

## Update for Forest 2.1.5 (2017-07-14)

> *Surely there's a simpler way, Sašo?*

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest,nicefrac}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{forestalias}
\forestset{
  left marble colour/.store in=\leftmarblecolour,
  right marble colour/.store in=\rightmarblecolour,
  left marble colour=black,
  right marble colour=red,
  declare count register={marble count},
  marble count'=0,
  declare toks={marble}{black},
  declare keylist={marbles}{},
  define long step={more marbles}{}{%
    filter={root,tree}{>O+tt=!{marbles}{}}},
  declare keylist={make more marbles}{},
  probability tree/.style={
    for tree={
      grow=0,
      s sep'+=2.5mm,
      delay={
        edge label/.process={
          OO_=?_ w2 {content} {n}{1}{below}{above} {node [midway, ##2, font=\scriptsize, text=black] {##1}}
        },
        content=,
      },
    },
    for descendants={
      if n=1{marble=\leftmarblecolour}{marble=\rightmarblecolour},
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      for tree={
        edge+/.option=marble,
        make marble=black,
      },
      where n children=0{
        tempkeylista'=,
        for nodewalk={
          c,
          while={>O_> {level}{1}}{u}
        }{
          spare marble/.option=marble,
          tempkeylista/.process={Rw{marble count}{m##1}},
        },
        marbles/.register=tempkeylista,
      }{},
    },
    make more marbles={
      for more marbles={
        tempcountc'=0,
        split option={marbles}{,}{make descendant marble},
      }
    },
    before drawing tree={
      where n children=0{
        TeX={\stepcounter{forestalias}},
        alias={n\theforestalias}
      }{}
    }
  },
  make descendant marble/.style={
    tempcountc'+=1,
    for nodewalk={L}{
      if={>O+tt={name}{#1}}{}{
        append/.expanded=#1, do dynamics
      }
    }
  },
  make marble/.style={circle, minimum width=2.5pt, fill=#1, draw=#1, inner sep=0pt},
  spare marble/.style={
    marble count'+=1,
    append/.expanded={[, make marble=#1, name=m\foresteregister{marble count}, grow=0, no edge, l'+=-10mm]},
  },
}
\begin{forest}(%
    stages={% customised definition of stages
      for root'={% nothing is removed from the standard forest definition - we only change it by adding to it
        process keylist register=default preamble,
        process keylist register=preamble,
      },
      process keylist=given options,
      process keylist=before typesetting nodes,
      % addition here
      process keylist=make more marbles,
      typeset nodes stage,
      process keylist=before packing,
      pack stage,
      process keylist=before computing xy,
      compute xy stage,
      process keylist=before drawing tree,
      draw tree stage,
    },
  )%
  probability tree,
  left marble colour=blue,
  [, name=t0 [\nicefrac{3}{5}[\nicefrac{5}{9}][\nicefrac{4}{9}]][\nicefrac{2}{5}, name=t1 [\nicefrac{2}{3}][\nicefrac{1}{3}, name=t2]]]
  \foreach \i/\j/\k/\l [count=\n] in {3/5/5/9,3/5/4/9,2/5/2/3,2/5/1/3}
  \node (l\n) at (n\n) [label={[label distance=2.5mm, inner sep=0pt, , font=\scriptsize]right:$\frac{\i}{\j}.\frac{\k}{\l}$}] {};
  \coordinate [above=7.5mm of t2] (m1);
  \path [draw, fill, font=\scriptsize\itshape] (m1 -| t0) circle (1pt) -- (m1 -| t1) node [midway, below] {first}  circle (1pt) -- (m1 -| t2) node [midway, below] {second}  circle (1pt) -- ([xshift=2.5mm]m1 -| n3) node [midway, below] {result} circle (1pt) -- ++(7.5mm,0) node [midway, below] {\phantom{l}p\phantom{l}} circle (1pt);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Note that this could be done without redefining `stages`, I assume. I just found it easier to use that to experiment with the ordering. Unlike the original code, this relies on `do dynamics`, which is experimental. It does, however, produce a similar result:

[image: v. 2.1.5 output]

## Original answer for earlier Forest (v. 1.something?)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest,nicefrac}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{forestalias}
\forestset{
  left marble colour/.store in=\leftmarblecolour,
  right marble colour/.store in=\rightmarblecolour,
  left marble colour=black,
  right marble colour=red,
  probability tree/.style={
    for tree={
      grow=0,
      marble=black,
      s sep+=2.5mm,
      if n=1{
        before typesetting nodes={
          edge label/.wrap pgfmath arg={node [midway, below, font=\scriptsize, text=black] {##1}}{content()},
        },
      }{
        before typesetting nodes={
          edge label/.wrap pgfmath arg={node [midway, above, font=\scriptsize, text=black] {##1}}{content()},
        },
      },
      before packing={
        content={},
        typeset node,
      },
    },
    for descendants={
      if n=1{make descendant marble=\leftmarblecolour}{make descendant marble=\rightmarblecolour},
    },
    before drawing tree={
      for tree={
        if n children=0{
          TeX={\stepcounter{forestalias}},
          alias={n\theforestalias}
        }{}
      }
    }
  },
  marble/.style={circle, minimum width=2.5pt, fill=#1, draw=#1, inner sep=0pt},
  make descendant marble/.style={
    edge=#1,
    delay n={int(level())}{
      for descendants={
        if n children=0{
          append={[, grow=0, marble=#1, no edge, l+=-10mm]}
        }{},
      },
    },
  },
}
\begin{forest}
  probability tree,
  left marble colour=blue
  [, name=t0 [\nicefrac{3}{5}[\nicefrac{5}{9}][\nicefrac{4}{9}]][\nicefrac{2}{5}, name=t1 [\nicefrac{2}{3}][\nicefrac{1}{3}, name=t2]]]
  \foreach \i/\j/\k/\l [count=\n] in {3/5/5/9,3/5/4/9,2/5/2/3,2/5/1/3}
    \node (l\n) at (n\n) [label={[label distance=2.5mm, inner sep=0pt, , font=\scriptsize]right:$\frac{\i}{\j}.\frac{\k}{\l}$}] {};
  \coordinate [above=7.5mm of t2] (m1);
  \path [draw, fill, font=\scriptsize\itshape] (m1 -| t0) circle (1pt) -- (m1 -| t1) node [midway, below] {first}  circle (1pt) -- (m1 -| t2) node [midway, below] {second}  circle (1pt) -- ([xshift=2.5mm]m1 -| n3) node [midway, below] {result} circle (1pt) -- ++(7.5mm,0) node [midway, below] {\phantom{l}p\phantom{l}} circle (1pt);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: probability tree]

Comment: The code in your answer doesn't produce the same output as your image - the results column only has the first set of dots. Please could you edit it?

Comment: @A.Goodier I think something has changed in Forest. I can't see how I can have got that using this method, but the code was obviously written before the current version of Forest became available. (At the least, before I got to grips with the new stuff, but I suspect from this, before it was published.)

Comment: @A.Goodier Please see edit above.