# Two questions: Math mode and tree diagrams for probability in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, formatting, trees

I am trying to print a worksheet for the math class I'm teaching and I was wondering if anyone can specifically help me out in two areas.

a) How do I get the output BAL1L2 without the slant?

```
     $BAL_{1}L_{2}$
```

b) And is there is an easier code out there to create tree diagrams for probability?

Comment: You need to register first to make you have some privileges.

Comment: It sounds like you need to read a good introduction to math typesetting. I recommend the `mathmode` document (available via `texdoc`).  For regular text in math mode, load the `amsmath` package, and use `\text{foo}`, unless the element has a specific semantics in which case there are other ways. As for your second question, easier than what?  There are plenty of examples already on the site: [Probability tree using TikZ for Bernoulli experiments?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19855) and [What is a more efficient way to draw this tree?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113315).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\(\mathrm{BAL_{1}L_{2}\)` to remove the slant.

The best tree-diagram program out there is [`pgf-tkiz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), but you could also hack out something with [`dirtree`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dirtree).

More on probability trees with pgf at this link: [Example: Probability tree](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/probability-tree/)

Some dirtree stuff here: [(Semi-)automatic directory-tree in LaTeX](http://texblog.org/tag/dirtree/)

Comment: Small (but crucial) typo: should be `\mathrm`, not `mathrm`. Also, `\( \)` is recommended over `$ $`.

Comment: Huh, so I learned something today. I had it backwards, I thought `$ $` was the LaTeX one, and `\( \)` was the old TeX one. Edited.

Comment: And, to be fussy, `\(\mathtrm{BAL}_{1}\mathrm{L}_{2}\)` should be preferred.

Comment: Too much typing, I'm a c++ programmer at heart haha.

Answer (score 1):

A recommended tree with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-tree}

\psset{treemode=R,edge=\ncline}

\def\ABCD{%
    \psTree{\Tcircle{A}} 
        \psTree{\Tcircle{B}} 
            \pstree[edge={\ncline[linecolor=red]}]{\Tcircle{C}}{\Tcircle{D}}\taput{\tiny an example}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{D}}{\Tcircle{C}}
        \endpsTree
        \psTree{\Tcircle{C}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{B}}{\Tcircle{D}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{D}}{\Tcircle{B}}
        \endpsTree
        \psTree{\Tcircle{D}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{B}}{\Tcircle{C}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{C}}{\Tcircle{B}}
        \endpsTree
    \endpsTree
}

\def\BACD{%
    \psTree{\Tcircle{B}} 
        \psTree{\Tcircle{A}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{C}}{\Tcircle{D}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{D}}{\Tcircle{C}}
        \endpsTree
        \psTree{\Tcircle{C}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{A}}{\Tcircle{D}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{D}}{\Tcircle{A}}
        \endpsTree
        \psTree{\Tcircle{D}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{A}}{\Tcircle{C}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{C}}{\Tcircle{A}}
        \endpsTree
    \endpsTree
}

\def\CABD{%
    \psTree{\Tcircle{C}} 
        \psTree{\Tcircle{A}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{B}}{\Tcircle{D}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{D}}{\Tcircle{B}}
        \endpsTree
        \psTree{\Tcircle{B}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{A}}{\Tcircle{D}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{D}}{\Tcircle{A}}
        \endpsTree
        \psTree{\Tcircle{D}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{A}}{\Tcircle{B}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{B}}{\Tcircle{A}}
        \endpsTree
    \endpsTree
}

\def\DABC{%
    \psTree{\Tcircle{D}} 
        \psTree{\Tcircle{A}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{B}}{\Tcircle{C}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{C}}{\Tcircle{B}}
        \endpsTree
        \psTree{\Tcircle{B}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{A}}{\Tcircle{C}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{C}}{\Tcircle{A}}
        \endpsTree
        \psTree{\Tcircle{C}} 
            \pstree{\Tcircle{A}}{\Tcircle{B}}
            \pstree{\Tcircle{B}}{\Tcircle{A}}
        \endpsTree
    \endpsTree
}

\begin{document}
\psTree[thislevelsep=0]{\Tn}
    \ABCD
    \BACD
    \CABD
    \DABC
\endpsTree
\end{document}
```

[image]