# Neural Network representation

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, algorithms

I would like to translate to Spanish a diagram that **represents a neural network**, the diagrama is something like this:
[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]

I would like to clone the design and effects, so I need some examples to do this,also I think that this image is something harder:
[image: Step3]

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Only effects needed here are the `ball shading` and the arrow style. The rest is pretty straightforward node placement. If you want something fancier see this [probability tree](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17549/). Lastly, either there is no Spanish needed here or I now realize that I can read the graph  pretty fluently.

Comment: Hi Fernando. In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: If you're struggling to get started, take a look at the example here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/neural-network/ ... Then post your code and gurus here can suggest changes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I went ahead and used Fernando Martinez's example to get me started. This uses LuaLaTex:

```
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%%Create a style for the arrows we are using
\tikzset{normal arrow/.style={draw,-triangle 45}}

%%Create the different coordinates to place layer 1 nodes
\path (0,0) coordinate (l1n1) ++(0,-2) coordinate (l1n2) ++(0,-2) coordinate (l1n3) ++(0,-2) coordinate (l1n4) ++(0,-2) coordinate (l1n5) ++(0,-2) coordinate (l1n6) ++(0,-2) coordinate (l1n7) ++(0,-2) coordinate (l1n8) ++(0,-2) coordinate (l1n9);

%%Create the different coordinates to place INPUT layer (xs)
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}{ \path (l1n\i) ++(-5,1) coordinate (x\i); }

%%Create the different coordinates to place Outputs
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}{ \path (l1n\i) ++(8,-1) coordinate (o\i); }

%%generate the second level top node points
\path ($(l1n1)!.5!(l1n2)!5 cm!90:(l1n2)$) coordinate (l2n0);

%%Create the different coordinates to place second layer nodes
\path (l2n0) ++(0,-2) coordinate (l2n1) ++(0,-2) coordinate (l2n2) ++(0,-2) coordinate (l2n3) ++(0,-2) coordinate (l2n4) ++(0,-2) coordinate (l2n5) ++(0,-2) coordinate (l2n6) ++(0,-2) coordinate (l2n7);

%%generate the position of last second level node point
\path ($(l1n5)!.5!(l1n6)!3 cm!90:(l1n6)$) coordinate (l2nx);


%%Place nodes
\foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6}{
    \node[draw,circle] (cl2n\i) at (l2n\i) {\phantom{a}$\sigma_\i\phantom{a}$};
}
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}{
    \node[draw,circle] (cl1n\i) at (l1n\i) {\phantom{a}$\sigma_{\directlua{tex.sprint(\i + 6)}}\phantom{a}$};
}

%%Label output nodes
\node (lo1) at (o1) {build wind float};
\node (lo2) at (o2) {build wind non-float};
\node (lo2) at (o3) {vehic wind float};
\node (lo3) at (o4) {vehic wind non-float};
\node (lo4) at (o5) {containers};
\node (lo5) at (o6) {tableware};
\node (lo6) at (o7) {headlamps};

%%Label input nodes
\node (nx1) at (x1) {$RI$};
\node (nx2) at (x2) {$Na$};
\node (nx3) at (x3) {$Mg$};
\node (nx4) at (x4) {$Al$};
\node (nx5) at (x5) {$Si$}; 
\node (nx6) at (x6) {$K$};
\node (nx7) at (x7) {$Ca$};
\node (nx8) at (x8) {$Ba$};
\node (nx9) at (x9) {$Fe$};

%%Drawing arrows 
%%Transparent arrows between input and Layer1
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}{
    \foreach \j in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}{
        \path[normal arrow, Cyan, draw opacity=0.2] (nx\i) -- (cl1n\j);
    }
}

%%Explicit arrows between Al and Layer1
\foreach \i/\val in {1/4.8,2/-0.14,3/-6.75,4/4.07,5/-2.88,6/14.18,7/-12.79,8/-2.41}{ 
    \newcommand\dosomecoolmath{\directlua{ x = 0.862679-(\i)*(-0.000529583) + ((-\i)^(2))*(-0.14934524) tex.sprint(x)}}
    \path[normal arrow, draw opacity=0.5] (nx4) -- node[above=\dosomecoolmath em] {$\mathbf{w_{(x4)\directlua{tex.sprint(\i + 6)}} = \val}$} (cl1n\i);
}

%%Explicit arrows between Layer1 and Layer2
\foreach \i/\val in {1/-0.199, 2/2.1155,3/-2.921,4/-7.29,5/-3.38,6/6.724,7/-2.56,8/4.470}{ 
    \newcommand\dosomecoolmath{
        \directlua{x = 8.862679-(\i)*(-0.000529583) + ((-\i)^(2))*(-0.22934524)
        tex.sprint(x)}}
        \path[normal arrow, draw opacity=0.7] (cl1n\i) -- node[above=\dosomecoolmath em] {$\mathbf{w_{(\directlua{tex.sprint(\i + 6)})4} = \val}$} (cl2n4);
        \foreach \j in {0,1,2,3,5,6}{
            \path[normal arrow, Cyan, draw opacity=0.2] (cl1n\i) -- (cl2n\j);
        }
}

%Draw final threshold
\path (o5) ++(0,-.5) coordinate (thres); \node (threshold) at (thres) {\fbox{$-3.617302530741029$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:[image: Results]

Answer (score 21):

I had some spare time while my simulation was running, so here you are. The code has some annotation and should speak pretty much for itself. If you have specific questions, feel free to ask. It should be straightforward to modify this to get the second picture.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    %%Create a style for the arrows we are using
    \tikzset{normal arrow/.style={draw,-triangle 45,very thick}}
    %%Create the different coordinates to place the nodes
    \path (0,0) coordinate (1) ++(0,-2) coordinate (2) ++(0,-2) coordinate (3);
    \path (1) ++(-3,-.2) coordinate (x1);
    \path (3) ++(-3, .2) coordinate (x2);
    %%Use the calc library and partway modifiers to generate the second and third level points
    \path ($(1)!.5!(2)!3 cm!90:(2)$) coordinate (4);
    \path ($(2)!.5!(3)!3 cm!90:(3)$) coordinate (5);
    \path ($(4)!.5!(5)!3 cm!90:(5)$) coordinate (6);
    \path (6) ++(3,0) coordinate (7);
    %%Place nodes at each point using the foreach construct
    \foreach \i/\color in {1/Magenta!60,2/MidnightBlue!60,3/CadetBlue!80,4/CadetBlue!80,5/CadetBlue!80,6/CadetBlue!80}{
      \node[draw,circle,shading=axis,top color=\color, bottom color=\color!black,shading angle=45] (n\i) at (\i) {$f_{\i}(e)$};
    }
    %%Place the remaining nodes separately
    \node (nx1) at (x1) {$\mathbf{x_1}$};
    \node (nx2) at (x2) {$\mathbf{x_2}$};
    \node (ny)  at (7)  {$\mathbf{y}$};
    %%Drawing the arrows
    \path[normal arrow] (nx1) -- (n1);
    \path[normal arrow] (nx1) -- (n3);
    \path[normal arrow] (nx2) -- (n1);
    \path[normal arrow] (nx2) -- (n3);
    \path[normal arrow] (n1)  -- (n4);
    \path[normal arrow] (n1)  -- (n5);
    \path[normal arrow] (n2)  -- (n4);
    \path[normal arrow] (n2)  -- (n5);
    \path[normal arrow] (n3)  -- (n4);
    \path[normal arrow] (n3)  -- (n5);
    \path[normal arrow] (n4)  -- (n6);
    \path[normal arrow] (n5)  -- (n6);
    \path[normal arrow] (n6)  -- (ny);
    %%Drawing the cyan arrows including the labels
    \path[normal arrow,Cyan] (nx1) -- node[above=.5em,Cyan] {$\mathbf{w_{(x1)2}}$} (n2);
    \path[normal arrow,Cyan] (nx2) -- node[below=.5em,Cyan] {$\mathbf{w_{(x2)2}}$} (n2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: TikZ Neural Net]

You will notice the colors and shadings are slightly different then in your picture. You can play around with the type of shading used and the colors used to get it closer to the original.

**EDIT:** with regards to your edit. You can just add the following for loop before the for loop that is already there. That will take care of creating the coordinates and nodes. It should be a straightforward extension to also add the arrows. Just use `dashed` and `red` as additional options.

```
%%Create new coordinates and nodes for offset nodes
\foreach \i/\color in {1/GreenYellow!60,2/Peach!60,4/GreenYellow!60,5/GreenYellow!60,6/GreenYellow!60}{
  \path (\i) ++(.5,.5) coordinate (o\i);
  \node[draw,circle,shading=axis,top color=\color, bottom color=\color!black,shading angle=45, minimum size=1.1cm] (no\i) at (o\i) {$\delta_\i$};
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'll implemented your solution

Answer (score 14):

Here are a couple of slightly different ways using `\matrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,matrix,positioning}
\tikzset{
  mymx/.style={matrix of math nodes,nodes=myball,column sep=4em,row sep=-1ex},
  myball/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=0pt},
  mylabel/.style={midway,sloped,fill=white,inner sep=1pt,outer sep=1pt,below,
    execute at begin node={$\scriptstyle},execute at end node={$}},
  plain/.style={draw=none,fill=none},
  sel/.append style={fill=green!10},
  prevsel/.append style={fill=red!10},
  route/.style={-latex,thick},
  selroute/.style={route,blue!50!green}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[mymx] (mx) {
    &|[prevsel]| f_1(e) \\
    |[plain]| x_1 && f_4(e) \\
    &|[sel]| f_2(e) && f_6(e) & |[plain]| y \\
    |[plain]| x_2 && f_5(e) \\
    & f_3(e) \\
  };
  {[route]
    \foreach \y in {2,4} {
      \draw (mx-\y-1) -- (mx-1-2);
      \draw (mx-\y-1) -- (mx-5-2);
      \draw (mx-\y-3) -- (mx-3-4); }
    \foreach \y in {1,3,5} {
      \draw (mx-\y-2) -- (mx-2-3);
      \draw (mx-\y-2) -- (mx-4-3); }
    \draw (mx-3-4) -- (mx-3-5);
  }
  {[selroute]
    \draw (mx-2-1) -- (mx-3-2) node[mylabel,above] { W_{(x1)2} };
    \draw (mx-4-1) -- (mx-3-2) node[mylabel] { W_{(x2)2} };
  }
  \node[above right=of mx.center]  {$ y_2 = f_2 (w_{(x1)2} x_1 + w_{(x2)2} x_2) $};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[mymx] (mx) {
    |[plain]| x_1 &|[prevsel,yshift=4ex]| f_1(e) & f_4(e) \\
    &|[prevsel]| f_2(e) && f_6(e) &|[plain]| y \\
    |[plain]| x_2 &|[sel,yshift=-4ex]| f_3(e) & f_5(e) \\
  };
  {[route]
    \foreach \y in {1,3} {
      \draw (mx-\y-1) -- (mx-1-2);
      \draw (mx-\y-1) -- (mx-2-2);
      \draw (mx-\y-3) -- (mx-2-4); }
    \foreach \y in {1,2,3} {
      \draw (mx-\y-2) -- (mx-1-3);
      \draw (mx-\y-2) -- (mx-3-3); }
    \draw (mx-2-4) -- (mx-2-5);
  }
  {[selroute]
    \draw (mx-1-1) -- (mx-3-2) node[mylabel] { W_{(x1)3} };
    \draw (mx-3-1) -- (mx-3-2) node[mylabel] { W_{(x2)3} };
  }
  \node[above right=of mx.center] {$ y_3 = f_3(w_{(x1)3}x_1 + w_{(x2)3} x_2) $};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I didn't try to reproduce the shadings because they were doing more harm, in my opinion, to readability than good.

It looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Somewhat late, but others may fancy trying my "neuralnetwork" package:

http://www.ctan.org/pkg/neuralnetwork

Samples are given in the github repository linked to on that page.

Read the `.sty` file for documentation.

Examples are given in the comments below.

The code for the poorly-proofed 3-layer network is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{neuralnetwork}

\begin{document}
    \begin{neuralnetwork}[height=4]
        \newcommand{\nodetextclear}[2]{}
        \newcommand{\nodetextx}[2]{$x_#2$}
        \newcommand{\nodetexty}[2]{$y_#2$}
        \inputlayer[count=4, bias=false, title=Input\\layer, text=\nodetextx]
        \hiddenlayer[count=5, bias=false, title=Hidden\\layer, text=\nodetextclear] \linklayers
        \outputlayer[count=3, title=Output\\layer, text=\nodetexty] \linklayers
    \end{neuralnetwork}
\end{document}
```

The code for the "exclusive or" network is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{neuralnetwork}

\begin{document}
    \begin{neuralnetwork}[height=2.5, layertitleheight=0, nodespacing=2.8cm, layerspacing=1.7cm]
        \newcommand{\nodetextclear}[2]{}
        \newcommand{\nodetextxnb}[2]{\ifnum0=#2 \else $x_#2$ \fi}
        \newcommand{\logiclabel}[1]{\,{$\scriptstyle#1$}\,}
        \newcommand{\nodetextY}[2]{$y$}
        \newcommand{\linklabelsU}[4]{\logiclabel{+1}}
        \newcommand{\linklabelsA}[4]{\ifnum0=#2 \logiclabel{+3} \else \logiclabel{-2} \fi}
        \setdefaultnodetext{\nodetextclear}
        % Input layer
        \inputlayer[count=2, bias=false, text=\nodetextxnb]
        % links to first hidden layer from input layer
        \hiddenlayer[count=3, bias=false, exclude={1, 3}]
            \link[from layer=0, to layer=1, from node=1, to node=2, label=\linklabelsA]
            \link[from layer=0, to layer=1, from node=2, to node=2, label=\linklabelsA]
        \hiddenlayer[count=2, bias=true, biaspos=center]
        % links to second hidden layer from input and first hidden layer
            \link[from layer=0, to layer=2, from node=1, to node=1, label=\linklabelsA]
            \link[from layer=1, to layer=2, from node=2, to node=1, label=\linklabelsA]
            \link[from layer=1, to layer=2, from node=2, to node=2, label=\linklabelsA]
            \link[from layer=0, to layer=2, from node=2, to node=2, label=\linklabelsA]
        \outputlayer[count=1, text=\nodetextY]
        % links to output layer from second hidden layer
            \link[from layer=2, to layer=3, from node=1, to node=1, label=\linklabelsA]
            \link[from layer=2, to layer=3, from node=2, to node=1, label=\linklabelsA]
        % links from bias node
            \link[from layer=2, to layer=1, from node=0, to node=2, label=\linklabelsA]
            \link[from layer=2, to layer=2, from node=0, to node=1, label=\linklabelsA]
            \link[from layer=2, to layer=2, from node=0, to node=2, label=\linklabelsA]
            \link[from layer=2, to layer=3, from node=0, to node=1, label=\linklabelsA]
    \end{neuralnetwork}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for the contribution. do you mind giving a sample for a teaser and for more access?

Comment: Here's an exclusive-OR gate, implemented as a neural network:
https://github.com/battlesnake/neural/blob/master/examples/xor.pdf?raw=true

Comment: And here's an example of why I should check my spacing before pushing an example to Github...
https://github.com/battlesnake/neural/blob/master/examples/neuralnetwork.pdf?raw=true

Comment: I meant including a small code example to show the ease of coding etc. The output is really nice but it doesn't show how difficult to get them.

Comment: While the syntax could probably be made more compact for simple layer-layer-layer networks, I hope that this is a decent compromise between simplicity and versatility!

Any feedback would be much appreciated!

Comment: Also, feel free to push any improvements / bugfixes taht you've probably had to make back to the git repository!