# Diagram of an artificial neural network

Tags: diagrams

I need draw some picture, but I don't know how do that.

First, the simple graph with basic shapes, arrow,....
[image]

And then, draw a picture with math symbol or equation in math environment. Like that:
[image]

Please help me draw two picture.
And if you don't mind, please show me some tools which can help me draw easily and generate to latex code, or some document help me learnt quickly.
Thanks for your help

Comment: You can use TikZ to do this.  Check out some of the examples in the manual: http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf

Comment: You can take a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/need-recommendations-for-a-drawing-tool-in-latex) which discusses a number of tools to choose from. Which you choose and want to stick at depends on a number of factors including your need, available time and learning curve option.

Comment: There are plenty of related questions on the site: [Fully connected network diagram](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86130) and [Neural Network representation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40718) are quite similar (if not duplicates) and have very good answers.

Comment: @dustin's link is now broken. Try this: http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf

Answer (score 60, accepted):

One possibility; the first diagram was drawn using a `matrix`; the second one, using `chains`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
plain/.style={
  draw=none,
  fill=none,
  },
net/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  nodes={
    draw,
    circle,
    inner sep=10pt
    },
  nodes in empty cells,
  column sep=2cm,
  row sep=-9pt
  },
>=latex
]
\matrix[net] (mat)
{
|[plain]| \parbox{1.3cm}{\centering Input\\layer} & |[plain]| \parbox{1.3cm}{\centering Hidden\\layer} & |[plain]| \parbox{1.3cm}{\centering Output\\layer} \\
& |[plain]| \\
|[plain]| & \\
& |[plain]| \\
  |[plain]| & |[plain]| \\
& & \\
  |[plain]| & |[plain]| \\
& |[plain]| \\
  |[plain]| & \\
& |[plain]| \\    };
\foreach \ai [count=\mi ]in {2,4,...,10}
  \draw[<-] (mat-\ai-1) -- node[above] {Input \mi} +(-2cm,0);
\foreach \ai in {2,4,...,10}
{\foreach \aii in {3,6,9}
  \draw[->] (mat-\ai-1) -- (mat-\aii-2);
}
\foreach \ai in {3,6,9}
  \draw[->] (mat-\ai-2) -- (mat-6-3);
\draw[->] (mat-6-3) -- node[above] {Ouput} +(2cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
init/.style={
  draw,
  circle,
  inner sep=2pt,
  font=\Huge,
  join = by -latex
},
squa/.style={
  draw,
  inner sep=2pt,
  font=\Large,
  join = by -latex
},
start chain=2,node distance=13mm
]
\node[on chain=2] 
  (x2) {$x_2$};
\node[on chain=2,join=by o-latex] 
  {$w_2$};
\node[on chain=2,init] (sigma) 
  {$\displaystyle\Sigma$};
\node[on chain=2,squa,label=above:{\parbox{2cm}{\centering Activate \\ function}}]   
  {$f$};
\node[on chain=2,label=above:Output,join=by -latex] 
  {$y$};
\begin{scope}[start chain=1]
\node[on chain=1] at (0,1.5cm) 
  (x1) {$x_1$};
\node[on chain=1,join=by o-latex] 
  (w1) {$w_1$};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[start chain=3]
\node[on chain=3] at (0,-1.5cm) 
  (x3) {$x_3$};
\node[on chain=3,label=below:Weights,join=by o-latex] 
  (w3) {$w_3$};
\end{scope}
\node[label=above:\parbox{2cm}{\centering Bias \\ $b$}] at (sigma|-w1) (b) {};

\draw[-latex] (w1) -- (sigma);
\draw[-latex] (w3) -- (sigma);
\draw[o-latex] (b) -- (sigma);

\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] (x1.north west) -- node[left=10pt] {Inputs} (x3.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. can you introduce me some document or software about tikz?

Comment: @phuong the pgf manual has numerous examples and some nice inroductory tutorials: http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf There's also a shorter document: http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf (I've never used this last one).

Comment: Thanks you for your document. It's very useful.
I just need 1 requirement. on the second graph, I want to remove a vertical line of circle. I tried hard but not done. Would you please help me again?

Comment: @phuong Sure! The problem is I am not sure exactly which line you are referring to. Do you want to suppress the arrow going from "Bias b" to the "Sigma"?

Comment: No, not bias. I want to remove circles between x_1 & w_1; x_2 &w_2; x_3 and W_3. You can see again my graph on question to know exactly.

Comment: @phuong Ah, now I see. Please see my updated answer. Is it that what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: @ Gonzalo Medina I'm so sorry, I wrote wrong, my mistake. I don't want to remove circle. I just want remove the first vector from x_1, x_2, x_3 to circle. keep circle, don't remove it. It's so difficult to write by word. If you don't mind, Please look again my second graph. One more time, I'm sorry about my mistake. Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: @phuong No problem. I updated my answer. I hope this time the result is what you expected.

Comment: Don't know why, but the first diagram doesn't compile on my end.

Comment: Figured it is due to beamer, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/single-ampersand-used-with-wrong-catcode-error-using-tikz-matrix-in-beamer
Either declare the frame `fragile` or use `ampersand replacement`