# Drawing a Neural Network architecture

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I need to draw an image like this:

[image]

I saw [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132444/diagram-of-an-artificial-neural-network) and [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/neural-network/), but I could not modify it properly. Basically, I could not write the on the labels. Need your help.

Comment: Please, show the code you used. The questions you linked are very good as starting point, what you need is to add some label on the nodes.

Comment: Have you tried `\draw (a) -- node[above,sloped] {x} (b);` for the edges and `\node[label=90:$\varphi_1$] (phi1) at (x,y) {};`?

Comment: Is it important that each edge meets at the border around the node?  That is, is it ok if the edges seem to 'meet' somewhere in the center of the node, with the node overlaid atop the meeting point?

Comment: @SeanAllred That minute things don't make a difference. What is important is the structure of the network.

Comment: I more than suspected, but this concession makes it *a lot* easier to implement, as you can see with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an idea how to do it:

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   cnode/.style={draw=black,fill=#1,minimum width=3mm,circle},
]
    \node[cnode=red,label=0:$\Sigma$] (s) at (6,-3) {};
    \node at (0,-4) {$\vdots$};
    \node at (3,-4) {$\vdots$};
    \foreach \x in {1,...,4}
    {   \pgfmathparse{\x<4 ? \x : "n"}
        \node[cnode=blue,label=180:$x_{\pgfmathresult}$] (x-\x) at (0,{-\x-div(\x,4)}) {};
        \node[cnode=gray,label=90:$\varphi_{\pgfmathresult}$] (p-\x) at (3,{-\x-div(\x,4)}) {};
        \draw (p-\x) -- node[above,sloped,pos=0.3] {$\omega_{\pgfmathresult}$} (s);
    }
    \foreach \x in {1,...,4}
    {   \foreach \y in {1,...,4}
        {   \draw (x-\x) -- (p-\y);
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]