# Drawing Autoassociative Neural Network Diagram [Beginner]

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I just want to draw the following image:

[image]

The examples I found in internet (see [example1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140782/drawing-a-neural-network-architecture), [example2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385119/drawing-a-neural-network-with-bias-with-tikz), [example3](http://tex.bootmath.com/drawing-neural-network-with-tikz.html)) cannot draw layers that are properly aligned.

For example, below is what I have tried.
[image]

Actually, I never used latex or tikz-pgf. Can anybody help me to draw the above neural network with a simple easy-to-understand code (I am very beginner).

Comment: I guess it will be rather straightforward to reproduce your scan, but you might learn more if you post your attempt and say where you got stuck. I also do not quite understand what you mean by "(not) properly aligned".

Comment: @marmot, in the second image, the first node of the hidden layer starts below the first node of input layer. Not properly placed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. If you've never used LaTeX before, then this may not be the best place to start. Do you have an independent need to learn LaTeX or do you just want to draw this diagram? But regardless, unless you post a minimal document  showing what you've done (not just an image) and explain exactly what needs to be corrected, there's no reason not to simply close this question as a duplicate of the others you've linked to.

Comment: @Alan Munn, I just want to draw this diagram. I do not need to learn it very much. If I got some sample code with similar structure like first figure, then I can customize it for my purpose. I tried some other code. But, I failed.

Comment: If you only want the diagram, I would use a GUI drawing program to do it. It will be faster, and you can get exactly what you want. Here you're just asking others to do your work for you.

Comment: 1) GUI drawing program is not giving quite good shape compared to the given one. 2) As I don't have much idea, it seems to me that the above figure is not hard to create if you have some idea about latex or if you get a good starting program. So, I asked. @AlanMunn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that the following will provide you with some motivation to have a look at the pgfmanual.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,positioning}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\pattern@density
\tikzset{/tikz/.cd,
    pattern density/.store in=\density,
    pattern density=3pt
}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\density]{resizable north east lines}
{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}
{\pgfqpoint{\density}{\density}}
{\pgfqpoint{\density}{\density}}
{
    \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
    \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\density + 0.1pt}{\density + 0.1pt}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{circlenode/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=1cm},
dotnode/.style={circle,draw,fill,minimum size=2mm},
myarrow/.style={-latex,thick}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw [pattern=resizable north east lines, pattern color=black,pattern density=3pt]
(-0.5,1) rectangle (-0.3,8);
\filldraw [pattern=resizable north east lines, pattern color=black,pattern density=3pt]
(-0.2,1) rectangle (0,8) coordinate (O);
\node[circlenode] (X1) at (1,7){};
\node[circlenode,below=1cm of X1] (X2){};
\node[circlenode,below=2cm of X2] (X3){};
\path (X2.south) -- (X3.north) node[pos=1/3,dotnode]{}  node[pos=2/3,dotnode]{};
\foreach \i in {1,2,3}
{\draw[myarrow] (O|-X\i) -- (X\i);}
%
\node[circlenode] (Y1) at (4,9){};
\node[circlenode,below=1cm of Y1] (Y2){};
\node[circlenode,below=3cm of Y2] (Y3){};
\node[circlenode,below=1cm of Y3] (Y4){};
\path (Y2.south) -- (Y3.north) node[pos=1/4,dotnode]{}  node[pos=1/2,dotnode]{} 
node[pos=3/4,dotnode]{};
\draw[thick] (X1.east) -- (Y1.west);
\draw[thick] (X1.east) -- (Y4.west);
\draw[thick] (X2.east) -- (Y2.west);
\draw[thick] (X2.east) -- (Y3.west);
\draw[thick] (X3.east) -- (Y1.west);
\draw[thick] (X3.east) -- (Y2.west);
\draw[thick] (X3.east) -- (Y4.west);
%
\node[circlenode] (Z1) at (7,6.5){};
\node[circlenode,below=2cm of Z1] (Z2){};
\path (Z1.south) -- (Z2.north) node[pos=1/3,dotnode]{}  node[pos=2/3,dotnode]{};
\draw[thick] (Y1.east) -- (Z1.west);
\draw[thick] (Y2.east) -- (Z1.west);
\draw[thick] (Y2.east) -- (Z2.west);
\draw[thick] (Y3.east) -- (Z2.west);
\draw[thick] (Y4.east) -- (Z1.west);
\draw[thick] (Y4.east) -- (Z2.west);
%
\node[circlenode] (U1) at (10,9){};
\node[circlenode,below=1cm of U1] (U2){};
\node[circlenode,below=3cm of U2] (U3){};
\node[circlenode,below=1cm of U3] (U4){};
\path (U2.south) -- (U3.north) node[pos=1/4,dotnode]{}  node[pos=1/2,dotnode]{} 
node[pos=3/4,dotnode]{};
\draw[thick] (Z1.east) -- (U1.west);
\draw[thick] (Z1.east) -- (U2.west);
\draw[thick] (Z1.east) -- (U4.west);
\draw[thick] (Z2.east) -- (U1.west);
\draw[thick] (Z2.east) -- (U3.west);
\draw[thick] (Z2.east) -- (U4.west);
%
\node[circlenode] (V1) at (13,7){};
\node[circlenode,below=1.5cm of V1] (V2){};
\node[circlenode,below=1.5cm of V2] (V3){};
\draw[thick] (U1.east) -- (V1.west);
\draw[thick] (U1.east) -- (V3.west);
\draw[thick] (U2.east) -- (V2.west);
\draw[thick] (U2.east) -- (V3.west);
\draw[thick] (U3.east) -- (V1.west);
\draw[thick] (U3.east) -- (V1.west);
\draw[thick] (U4.east) -- (V2.west);
\draw[thick] (U4.east) -- (V3.west);
%

\filldraw [pattern=resizable north east lines, pattern color=black,pattern density=3pt]
(14.2,1) rectangle (14,8) coordinate (O2);
\foreach \i in {1,2,3}
{\draw[myarrow] (V\i) -- (O2|-V\i);}
\filldraw [pattern=resizable north east lines, pattern color=black,pattern density=3pt]
(14.3,1) rectangle (14.5,8);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many compliments again, +1.