# Help drawing a back-propagation neural network architecture with the given code

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes

I have a request regarding how to draw a ANN using latex/tikz. I am using this [example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/neural-network/) as base, even though it is outdated, is the one that I found to be easy for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\layersep{2.5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
\tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
\tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
\tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=red!50];
\tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=blue!50];
\tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

% Draw the input layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,4}
% This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
    \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};

% Draw the hidden layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,5}
    \path[yshift=0.5cm]
        node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};

% Draw the output layer node
\node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H-3] (O) {};

% Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
% hidden layer.
\foreach \source in {1,...,4}
    \foreach \dest in {1,...,5}
        \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);

% Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
\foreach \source in {1,...,5}
    \path (H-\source) edge (O);

% Annotate the layers
\node[annot,above of=H-1, node distance=1cm] (hl) {Hidden layer};
\node[annot,left of=hl] {Input layer};
\node[annot,right of=hl] {Output layer};
\end{tikzpicture}
% End of code
\end{document}
```

It gives this image:

[image]

What I want to be able to do is:

Draw a simple back-propagation NN, like the one already answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162326/drawing-back-propagation-neural-network), but I don't how to implement using the code I gave.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362663/drawing-local-neuro-fuzzy-architecture/362705#362705. your question is almost duplicate to it :-)

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a link and attribute the code you got from somebody else. It is only common courtesy to acknowledge the source. Please also note that the site works best when you ask one question per question.

Comment: @cfr Thank you! I already made the changes you proposed.

Comment: Thanks. Is there some reason you don't want to use the code in the answer you linked to? I ask because when I've needed to draw neural networks, I think I've used the `matrix` library, because it seems a bit more straightforward that way and easier to make modify as necessary.

Comment: @cfr Only because I don't know how to use it, I want to keep the same design as the image above, I don't know if I can keep it using different approaches for each NN arquiteture. I now I can draw easily a feed-forward if the code I posted, but not a feed-forward one, and vice versa.

Comment: You can use the names of the nodes given in your loops instead of the node names given automatically by the matrix configuration. Then draw the arrows in the same way. I think it is simpler with the matrix, but if you know how to use the loops, just go with that and use the names you've got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the loops you have given names for the nodes, `I-number` for the left, `H-number` for the middle and `O` for the right node. As help I use the tikz library `calc` and specify a coordinate between the two upper nodes `H-1` and `I-1`. Then draw an arrow from `O` to this one.

In the code below the library `positioning` is added, which gives an easy way to position nodes by use of e.g. `left=of H-1`. You can also remove the `\tikzstyle` and use an argument to set the style of the picture. There are aslo some more updtates in the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\layersep{2.5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep,
  %every pin edge={<-,shorten <=1pt},
  neuron/.style={circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt},
  input neuron/.style={neuron, fill=green!50},
  output neuron/.style={neuron, fill=red!50},
  hidden neuron/.style={neuron, fill=blue!50},
  annot/.style = {text width=4em, text centered}
  ]
  % Draw the input layer nodes
  \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,4}
  % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
  \node[input neuron, pin={[pin edge={<-,shorten <=1pt}]left:Input \#\y}] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};

  % Draw the hidden layer nodes
  \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,5}
  \node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm+0.5cm) {};

  % Draw the output layer node
  \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right=of H-3] (O) {};

  % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
  % hidden layer.
  \foreach \source in {1,...,4}
  \foreach \dest in {1,...,5}
  \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);

  % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
  \foreach \source in {1,...,5}
  \path (H-\source) edge (O);

  % Annotate the layers
  \node[annot,above=15mm of H-1] (hl) {Hidden layer};
  \node[annot,left=of hl] {Input layer};
  \node[annot,right=of hl] {Output layer};
  %%% 
  \coordinate (H-I-1) at ($(H-1)!0.5!(I-1)$);
  \draw (O) |- ($(H-I-1) +(0,1)$) node[above,pos=0.75]{Back propagation} -- (H-I-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
% End of code
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This could be improved by updating the deprecated syntax e.g. `\tikzstyle` and `right of` etc.

Comment: @cfr what is used now?

Comment: @cfr, You are right, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @CaioCustódio, By using the tikz library `positioning` you can use `right=of H-1` (the equallity sign is positioned before of). This is more general and you can for example easily change the distance by `right=1cm of H-1`.