# Neural Network Graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I would be mostly obliged if you can help me: 
I would like to insert a graph like this:

[image]

In my case, I need 3 inputs, 4 hidden layers and 2 outputs.

I know that there are similar topics, but I do not understand how to modify the code.

Thank you.

EDIT

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
plain/.style={
    draw=none,
    fill=none,
},
net/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes={
        draw,
        circle,
        inner sep=8.5pt
    },
    nodes in empty cells,
    column sep=0.6cm,
    row sep=-11pt
},
>=latex
]
\matrix[net] (mat)
{
    |[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Input\\layer} & |[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Hidden\\layer} & |[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Output\\layer} \\
    & |[plain]| \\
    |[plain]| & \\
    & |[plain]| \\
    |[plain]| & |[plain]| \\
    & & \\
    |[plain]| & |[plain]| \\
    & |[plain]| \\
    |[plain]| & \\
    & |[plain]| \\
};
\foreach \ai [count=\mi ]in {2,4,...,10}
\draw[<-] (mat-\ai-1) -- node[above] {I\mi} +(-1cm,0);
\foreach \ai in {2,4,...,10}
{\foreach \aii in {3,6,9}
    \draw[->] (mat-\ai-1) -- (mat-\aii-2);
}
\foreach \ai in {3,6,9}
\draw[->] (mat-\ai-2) -- (mat-6-3);
\draw[->] (mat-6-3) -- node[above] {O1} +(1cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I do not understand how to add or remove units. Most importantly, what does `\ai` or `\aii` stand for?

Comment: By "similar topics", do you mean  e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132444/? If you were to point us to the code you had in mind, someone could tell you how to modify it.

Comment: Please add a minimal working example (MWE) showing what have you done till now and explaining your problem, if you don't know how to create it, see [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)!

Comment: `ai` and `aii` are [loop variables](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86904/why-do-most-of-us-use-i-as-a-loop-counter-variable).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Diagram of an artificial neural network](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132444/diagram-of-an-artificial-neural-network)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
plain/.style={
    draw=none,
    fill=none,
},
net/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes={
        draw,
        circle,
        inner sep=8.5pt
    },
    nodes in empty cells,
    column sep=0.6cm,
    row sep=-11pt
},
>=latex
]

\matrix[net] (mat)
{
    |[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Input\\layer} & |[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Hidden\\layer} & |[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Output\\layer} \\
    |[plain]| & \\
    & |[plain]| \\
    |[plain]| & &  \\
    & |[plain]| \\
    |[plain]| & &  \\
    & |[plain]| \\
    |[plain]| & \\
};
\foreach \ai [count=\mi ]in {3,5,7}
\draw[<-] (mat-\ai-1) -- node[above] {Input \mi} +(-2cm,0);
\foreach \ai in {3,5,7}
{\foreach \aii in {2,4,...,8}
    \draw[->] (mat-\ai-1) -- (mat-\aii-2);
}
\foreach \ai in {2,4,...,8}
\draw[->] (mat-\ai-2) -- (mat-6-3);

\foreach \ai in {2,4,...,8}
\draw[->] (mat-\ai-2) -- (mat-4-3);

\foreach \ai [count=\mi ]in {4,6}
\draw[->] (mat-\ai-3) -- node[above] {Output \mi} +(2cm,0);
\foreach \ai in {3,5,7}
{\foreach \aii in {2,4,...,8}
    \draw[->] (mat-\ai-1) -- (mat-\aii-2);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Or:
See: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/neural-network/ (Kjell Magne Fauske)

Modification:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}

% Basis: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/neural-network/
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\layersep{2.5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!100, node distance=\layersep]
    \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=white!100,draw=black];
    \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=white!100,draw=black];
    \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=white!100,draw=black];
    \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

% Draw the input layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
% This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
    \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};

% Draw the hidden layer nodes
\foreach \name / \y in {1,...,4}
    \path[yshift=0.5cm]
        node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};

% Draw the output layer node
\node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H-2] (O1) {};
\node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H-3] (O2) {};

% Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
% hidden layer.
\foreach \source in {1,...,3}
    \foreach \dest in {1,...,4}
        \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);

% Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
\foreach \source in {1,...,4}
    \path (H-\source) edge (O1);
\foreach \source in {1,...,4}
    \path (H-\source) edge (O2);

% Annotate the layers
\node[annot,above of=H-1, node distance=1cm] (hl) {Hidden layer};
\node[annot,left of=hl] {Input layer};
\node[annot,right of=hl] {Output layer};

\end{tikzpicture}
% End of code
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Zarko The code from [the first revision of this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/354001/1) definitely produces two outputs, but perhaps it was edited within the grace period, so that it doesn't show as a separate revision.  (Bobyandbob: sorry for the noise.)

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand how those lines code work much better.

Comment: It would be better to use the `positioning` library's syntax for relative positioning.

Comment: @cfr Do you mean the `\foreach` loops, i don't know what i should change. Or could you edit the answer with your improvements?

Comment: I mean `right of=` is considered deprecated and the `positioning` library's alternative syntax is recommended. `right=of` etc.

Answer (score 6):

Since nobody actually demonstrated how to include 4 hidden layers, here's another one. This doesn't have 4 hidden layers either, but it does have more than 1.

Internal connection strength is indicated by opacity, varied randomly from 25% to 100%.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows.meta,quotes,shadows,decorations.pathreplacing,positioning,fadings}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\begin{document}
\colorlet{mewnol}{blue!75!cyan}%
\colorlet{allanol}{blue!50!black}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    lliw nn/.code={\colorlet{lliwnn}{#1}},
    lliw nn=mewnol,
    nn/.style={draw=lliwnn, inner color=white, outer color=lliwnn!5, circular drop shadow},
    font=\sffamily\plstyle,
    >=Latex,
    every edge/.append style={->},
    every edge quotes/.append style={font=\sffamily\plstyle\footnotesize,},
    semithick,
  ]
  \matrix (n) [matrix of nodes, nodes={circle, minimum size=20pt, thick}, nodes in empty cells, column sep=7.5mm, column 1/.append style={nodes={coordinate}}, column 12/.append style={nodes={coordinate}}, column 2/.append style={lliw nn=allanol}, column 11/.append style={lliw nn=allanol}]
  {
    &[10mm]&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&&&[10mm]\\
    &&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&&\\
    &|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&\\
    &&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&\\
    &|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&\\
    &&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&\\
    &|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&\\
    &&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&&\\
    &&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&|[nn]|&&&&\\
  };
  \foreach \i [count=\j from 1] in {3,5,7} \draw [allanol]  (n-\i-1) edge ["Input \j"] (n-\i-2) ;
  \foreach \i [count=\j from 1] in {4,6} \draw [allanol] (n-\i-11) edge ["Output \j"] (n-\i-12)  ;
  \begin{scope}[every edge/.append style={draw=mewnol, opacity={random(25,100)/100}}]
    \foreach \i in {3,5,7} \draw (n-\i-10) edge (n-4-11) edge (n-6-11);
    \foreach \i in {3,5,7} \foreach \j in {2,4,6,8} \draw (n-\i-2) edge (n-\j-3) (n-\j-9) edge (n-\i-10);
    \foreach \k [evaluate=\k as \m using {int(\k+1)}, evaluate=\k as \n using {int(\k+2)} ] in {3,5,7} \foreach \i in {2,4,6,8} \foreach \j in {1,3,5,7,9} \draw  (n-\i-\k) edge (n-\j-\m) (n-\j-\m) edge (n-\i-\n) ;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[decoration={brace, amplitude=7.5pt}, thick, every node/.append style={align=center}]
    \draw [decorate, mewnol] ([xshift=-2.5pt]n-1-3.west |- n-1-3.north) ++(0,7.5pt) coordinate (l) -- ([xshift=2.5pt]n-1-10.east |- l) node [above=7.5pt,midway] {Hidden\\Layers};
    \draw [decorate, allanol] ([xshift=-2.5pt]n-1-2.west |- l) -- ([xshift=2.5pt]n-1-2.east |- l) node [above=7.5pt,midway]  {Input\\Layer};
    \draw [decorate, allanol] ([xshift=-2.5pt]n-1-11.west |- l) -- ([xshift=2.5pt]n-1-11.east |- l) node [above=7.5pt,midway]  {Output\\Layer};
  \end{scope}
  \draw [thick, ->, allanol] ([xshift=-2.5pt,yshift=-10pt]current bounding box.south -| n-9-2.west) coordinate (ll) -- ([xshift=2.5pt]n-9-11.east |- ll) node [midway, below] {Flow of Information};
  \node (cs) [every edge quotes, anchor=base west, xshift=50mm, mewnol] at ([xshift=5pt,yshift=-12.5pt]n-1-1 |- current bounding box.south) {Connection Strength};
  \fill [fill=mewnol, path fading=west] (cs.base west) ++(-5pt,\pgflinewidth) rectangle ++(-50mm,5pt) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: neural net]

Answer (score 5):

This is more extended comment and exercise of understanding of *Bobyandbob* answer than new answer. My findings:

- kernel of image code is matrix with three column and  eight rows
- in the first rows are names of neural network layers
- in other rows the empty cells are used for showing nodes in neural network
- cells which are not used are in his answer designated with `|[plain]|`
- not all cells in matrix are explicit defined (this cause confusion)
- connections between nodes are drawn with nested loops (outer for left layer, inner for right layer)
- inputs and outputs are drawn in single loops

Changes which gives me better understanding of answer:

- strictly define all cell in matrix
- for mark unused cells define new style, for example `ec` (as empty cell)
- redefine style `plain` so, that in its use can be eliminated `\parbox{...}`

With this changes *Bobyandbob*'s MWE become:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm] {standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, % for edge arrows 
                matrix,      % nodes will set as matrix elements
                }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
           > = Stealth, semithick,
plain/.style = {draw=none, fill=none, yshift=11mm,
                text width=7ex,  align=center},% for text in images, 
   ec/.style = {draw=none},% for emty cells
  net/.style = {% for matrix style
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes={circle, draw, semithick, minimum size=12mm, inner sep=0mm},% circles in image
    nodes in empty cells,% for not used cells in matrix
  column sep = 16mm, % distance between columns in matrix 
     row sep = -3mm  % distance between rows in matrix
            },
]
\matrix[net] (m)% m is matrix name, it is used for names of cell: firs has name m-1-1
                % in empty space between ampersands will show circles: 
                % i.e.: nodes of the neural network
{
|[plain]| Input layer & |[plain]| Hidden layer  & |[plain]| Output layer  \\
|[ec]|                &                         & |[ec]|                  \\
                      & |[ec]|                  & |[ec]|                  \\
|[ec]|                &                         &                         \\
                      & |[ec]|                  & |[ec]|                  \\
|[ec]|                &                         &                         \\
                      & |[ec]|                  & |[ec]|                  \\
|[ec]|                &                         & |[ec]|                  \\
};
\% inputs
\foreach \in [count=\ir from 1] in {3,5,7}
\draw[<-] (m-\in-1.west) -- node[above] {Input \ir} +(-22mm,0);
% connections between nodes in the first and second layer
\foreach \j in {3,5,7}
{
\foreach \k in {2,4,6,8} \draw[->] (m-\j-1) -- (m-\k-2);
}
% connections between nodes in the second and third layer
\foreach \j in {2,4,6,8}
{
\foreach \k in {4,6} \draw[->] (m-\j-2) -- (m-\k-3);
}
% output
\draw[->] (m-4-3.east) -- node[above] {Output 1} +(22mm,0);
\draw[->] (m-6-3.east) -- node[above] {Output 2} +(22mm,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is (almost) the same as in *Bobyandbob*'s answer:

[image]

Between both MWE are also some minor, not inportant differences as used document class, size of nodes and determining coordinates used for inputs and outputs (added are anchors to node names).

Comment: Nice answer and comment.