# How to draw a network like this using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I want to draw a network like this using tikz.

[image]

I tried to draw it using Matrix but it needs some modifications!
My code:

```
\begin{figure}
\fbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}[   
  inner/.style={circle,draw=black!50,fill=white!20,thick,inner sep=5pt},
  outer/.style={ column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm},  
    innerbox/.style={fill=white!20,thick,innerbox},
    outerbox/.style={rectangle,draw=white,fill=white!20,thick,innerbox },
  outerT/.style={rectangle,draw=white,fill=white!20,thick,inner sep=10pt, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm},
  ]

  \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, outer, nodes={inner} ]{
    0 \\
     };

  \matrix (B) [matrix of nodes, outer, nodes={inner}, right=of A]{
    0 \\
    1 \\
        2\\
        \vdots\\
        n-1\\
        n\\
  };
\matrix (X) [matrix of nodes, outer, nodes={inner}, right=of B]{
  $\cdots$\\
  $\cdots$\\
  $\cdots$\\
  $\cdots$\\
  $\cdots$\\
    };
\matrix (C) [matrix of nodes, outer, nodes={inner}, right=of X]{
    0 \\
    1 \\
        2\\
    \vdots\\
        n-1\\
        n\\
  };

\matrix (D) [matrix of nodes, outer, nodes={inner}, right=of C]{
    0 \\
    1 \\
        2\\
        \vdots\\
        n-1\\
        n\\
  };
\matrix (E) [matrix of nodes, outer, nodes={inner}, right=of D]{
    1 \\
        2\\
        \vdots\\
        n-1\\
        n\\
  };
    \draw[black, thick] (A-1-1)--(B-2-1);
  \draw[black, thick] (A-1-1)--(B-3-1);
  \draw[black, thick] (A-1-1)--(B-5-1);
  \draw[black, thick] (A-1-1)--(B-6-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (B-1-1)--(C-2-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (B-1-1)--(C-3-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (B-1-1)--(C-5-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (B-1-1)--(C-6-1);
  \draw[black, thick] (C-1-1)--(D-2-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (C-1-1)--(D-3-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (C-1-1)--(D-5-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (C-1-1)--(D-6-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (D-1-1)--(E-1-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (D-1-1)--(E-2-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (D-1-1)--(E-4-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (D-1-1)--(E-5-1);

    \draw[black, thick] (B-2-1)--(C-3-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (B-2-1)--(C-5-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (B-2-1)--(C-6-1);

    \draw[black, thick] (B-3-1)--(C-2-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (B-3-1)--(C-5-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (B-3-1)--(C-6-1);

    \draw[black, thick] (B-5-1)--(C-2-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (B-5-1)--(C-3-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (B-5-1)--(C-6-1);

    \draw[black, thick] (B-6-1)--(C-2-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (B-6-1)--(C-3-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (B-6-1)--(C-5-1);

    \draw[black, thick] (C-2-1)--(D-3-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (C-2-1)--(D-5-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (C-2-1)--(D-6-1);

    \draw[black, thick] (C-3-1)--(D-2-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (C-3-1)--(D-5-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (C-3-1)--(D-6-1);

    \draw[black, thick] (C-5-1)--(D-2-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (C-5-1)--(D-3-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (C-5-1)--(D-6-1);

    \draw[black, thick] (C-6-1)--(D-2-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (C-6-1)--(D-3-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (C-6-1)--(D-5-1);

  \draw[black, thick] (D-1-1)--(E-1-1);
  \draw[black, thick] (D-1-1)--(E-2-1);
  \draw[black, thick] (D-1-1)--(E-4-1);
  \draw[black, thick] (D-1-1)--(E-5-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (D-2-1)--(E-2-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (D-2-1)--(E-4-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (D-2-1)--(E-5-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (D-3-1)--(E-1-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (D-3-1)--(E-4-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (D-3-1)--(E-5-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (D-5-1)--(E-1-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (D-5-1)--(E-2-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (D-5-1)--(E-5-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (D-6-1)--(E-1-1);
  \draw[black, thick] (D-6-1)--(E-2-1);
    \draw[black, thick] (D-6-1)--(E-4-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\caption{} 
\label{}
\end{figure}
```

I appreciate any comment in advance.

This is the output of my code. So ugly!

[image]

Comment: Hi ! Could you provide us a MWE  : https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Have a look to this question and answers: [Neural Network Graph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/353993/124842) (the last answer is quite similar to your picture)

Comment: Thanks  Bobyandbob. I saw that post before posing this question. My problem is how to insert that rectangular box with dot points inside . The rectangular should overlap some part of network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code shows how to use one `matrix` for all nodes and some `foreach` loops for links between nodes.

The frame, originally drawn with `\fbox`, is drawn with `show background rectangle` option.

Distance between columns 2 and 3 and rows 3 and 4 has been adjusted with `[...]` options inside `matrix` declaration.

After all links have been draw, a white filled area is created between second and third column where horizontal `\dots` can be easily placed.

That's all.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric, matrix, backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    show background rectangle, %Draws frame around tikzpicture   
    inner/.style={ellipse, draw=black!50, thick, minimum width=15mm},
  ]

  \matrix (A) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=10mm, column sep=22mm, nodes={inner}]{
    0 & 0 &[1cm] 0 & 0 & \\
      & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\[1cm]
      & n-1 & n-1 & n-1 & n-1 \\
      & n & n & n & n \\
     };

   % Lines from 0
    \foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \nj using int(\j), evaluate=\j as \nextj using int(\nj+1)] in {1,2,3,4}
        \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ni using int(\i)] in {2,3,4,5}
            \draw (A-1-\nj)--(A-\ni-\nextj);

    % Lines from 1,2,n-1,n      
    \foreach \j [evaluate=\j as \nj using int(\j), evaluate=\j as \nextj using int(\nj+1)] in {2,3,4}
    {
        \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ni using int(\i)] in {3,4,5}
            \draw (A-2-\nj)--(A-\ni-\nextj);
        \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ni using int(\i)] in {2,4,5}
            \draw (A-3-\nj)--(A-\ni-\nextj);
        \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ni using int(\i)] in {2,3,5}
            \draw (A-4-\nj)--(A-\ni-\nextj);
        \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ni using int(\i)] in {2,3,4}
            \draw (A-5-\nj)--(A-\ni-\nextj);
    }

    % Vertical dots
    \foreach \i in {2,3,4,5}
        \path (A-3-\i) -- node {$\vdots$} (A-4-\i);

    % White area between column 2 and 3
    \fill[white] ([xshift=5mm]A-1-2.north east) rectangle ([xshift=-5mm]A-5-3.south west);

    % Horizontal dots over previous white filled area
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5}
        \path (A-\i-2) -- node {$\dots$} (A-\i-3);

    % Diagonal dots 
    \path (A-3-2)--node {$\ddots$} (A-4-3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would do this using a series of `\foreach` loops to draw the nodes and the edges. Once all of the edges are drawn you can draw a rectangle with `fill=white` to get rid of the edges between the second and third columns. I drew the diagram on the integer lattice and then added `yscale=0.7` to make it look at little better.

Here's my output:

[image]

I think using at least some colour is essential to make the image look more readable.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=0.7,
  inner/.style={ellipse,minimum height=4mm, minimum width=8mm,draw=blue!80!black,fill=white!20,thick,inner sep=0pt},
  ]
  % first the nodes
  \node[inner] (00) at (0,5) {0};
  \foreach \c in {2,6,8} {
    \foreach \r/\lab in {0/n,1/n-1,3/2,4/1,5/0} {
       \node[inner] (\c\r) at (\c,\r) {\lab};
    }
  }
  \foreach \r/\lab in {0/n,1/n-1,3/2,4/1} {
     \node[inner] (10\r) at (10,\r) {\lab};
  }
  \foreach \c in {2,6,8,10} {
       \draw[loosely dotted, very thick] (\c,1.5)--++(0,1);
  }
  % now the edges
  \foreach \s in {0,1,3,4} {
     \draw(00)--(2\s);
  }
  \foreach \c [evaluate=\c as \cp using int(\c+2)] in {2,6,8} {
    \ifnum\c=2\def\cp{6}\fi
    \foreach \r in {0,1,3,4,5} {
      \foreach \s in {0,1,3,4} {
         \ifnum\r=\s\else
           \draw(\c\r)--(\cp\s);
         \fi
      }
    }
  }
  % white rectangle for the "missing" columns
  \draw[white,fill=white] (3,0) rectangle ++(2,5);
  % dots dots between columns
  \foreach \r in {0,1,1.4,1.8,2.2,2.6,3,4,5} {
     \draw[loosely dotted, very thick] (3.5,\r) -- ++(1,0);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help