# Create a Custom Neural Network Picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-cd

I'm currently searching for an effective tool to draw and import the following neural network picture into my thesis.

[image]

I have learned a lot thank to you guys w.r.t. TikZ but unfortunately my skills are insufficient to achieve something like this.

I have seen that there are some websites where you can draw and export to TikZ. Any recommendation on how to do this the best and easiest way ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524408/197451 ---- the code here is similar to what you require -- especially the u1, u2 vertical dots -- the arrows going right -- if you read the code i think you can get it

Comment: https://keras.io

Comment: http://www.dkriesel.com/en/science/neural_networks

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132444/diagram-of-an-artificial-neural-network -- have you gone through all these -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=neural%20network

Comment: @jsbibra Hi ! Thank you for the replies. Indeed I have searched through them but I'm still a beginner, I think that above structure is too complex for me, I don't even know hot to start right ... I think a template would be nice

Answer (score 1):

It may not handle this picture but Geogebra is helpful most of the time. It has a mac app that can export to Tikz as well. I do not know if they have a windows or linux version though.

Here: https://www.geogebra.org/graphing

Although, word of caution, this is probably not your best choice but will definitely help you get to somewhere at least.

Comment: Thank you, however I need the complex Gaussians, etc. I think its good for simpler stuff, but thank you nevertheless!

Comment: Note that you can generate functions and then get the tikz code for them in Geogebra. Also note that, (Assuming you have access to Matlab) there is a Matlab package called matlab2tikz which takes your plot and turns into a tikz code and you can play with that code. Here: (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz)