# How put figure on the inclined plane?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\nuPi{3.1459265}
\foreach \a in {0,6,12,18,24}{
\foreach \x in {0,3}{
\foreach \y in {0,2*sqrt(3),4*sqrt(3),6*sqrt(3)}{
  \foreach \i in {0,...,5}{
\draw [ultra thick,blue]({\x + \a+2*cos(360*\i/6)},{\y+sqrt(\x)+2*sin(360*\i/6)}) -- ({\x + \a+2*cos(360*(\i+1)/6)},{\y+sqrt(\x)+2*sin(360*(\i+1)/6)});
      \shade[ball color=red] ({\x + \a+2*cos(360*\i/6)},{\y+sqrt(\x)+2*sin(360*\i/6)}) circle(0.45);
    }
  }
 }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I put this picture of graphene on an inclined plane? All hexagons should be deformed, how can I make this deformations in TikZ?

Comment: Something like this: `\begin{tikzpicture}[xslant=.5]`?

Comment: @Sigur Looks close what I need, but there is no perspective. Without perspective it looks like deformed figure in the same plane.

Comment: Use `yslant` also. `[xslant=.5,yslant=.6]`

Comment: Can you show us what you mean? Which inclined plane do you mean? Is [Draw a Kohonen SOM feature map?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144366) related?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you for this reference. I'm beginner  in TikZ, but I use LaTeX already 20 years. I'm delighted with TikZ, it is really very helpful and useful package. I'll try to use your reference.

Answer (score 3):

Putting a box on an inclined plane with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{dimen=monkey,fillstyle=solid,opacity=.5}

\def\object{%
    \psframe[linestyle=none,fillcolor=blue](-2,-1)(2,1)
    \psaxes[linecolor=gray,labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(3,2)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \rput{*0}{%
        \psline{->}(0,-2)%
        \uput[-90]{*0}(0,-2){$\vec{w}$}}
}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+10}{5}{%
\begin{pspicture}(9,7)
    \pspolygon[fillcolor=gray](8,0)(!8 dup \i\space tan mul)
    \rput(5;\i){\rput{\i}{\rput(0,1){\object}}}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `xslant` and yslant` both with suitable values.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xslant=.6,yslant=.8]
  \def\nuPi{3.1459265}
\foreach \a in {0,6,12,18,24}{
\foreach \x in {0,3}{
\foreach \y in {0,2*sqrt(3),4*sqrt(3),6*sqrt(3)}{
  \foreach \i in {0,...,5}{
      \draw [ultra thick,blue,]({\x + \a+2*cos(360*\i/6)},{\y+sqrt(\x)+2*sin(360*\i/6)}) -- ({\x + \a+2*cos(360*(\i+1)/6)},{\y+sqrt(\x)+2*sin(360*(\i+1)/6)});
      \shade[ball color=red] ({\x + \a+2*cos(360*\i/6)},{\y+sqrt(\x)+2*sin(360*\i/6)}) circle(0.45);
    }
  }
 }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can check for suitable values of `xslant` and `yslant` this way. (takes time to compile)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\foreach \xslant in {.4,.8}{
\foreach \yslant in {.1,.2,...,.9}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \useasboundingbox (-8,-8) rectangle (65,45);
  \def\nuPi{3.1459265}
\foreach \a in {0,6,12,18,24}{
\foreach \x in {0,3}{
\foreach \y in {0,2*sqrt(3),4*sqrt(3),6*sqrt(3)}{
  \foreach \i in {0,...,5}{
      \draw [ultra thick,blue,xslant=\xslant,yslant=\yslant]({\x + \a+2*cos(360*\i/6)},{\y+sqrt(\x)+2*sin(360*\i/6)}) -- ({\x + \a+2*cos(360*(\i+1)/6)},{\y+sqrt(\x)+2*sin(360*(\i+1)/6)});
      \shade[ball color=red,xslant=\xslant,yslant=\yslant] ({\x + \a+2*cos(360*\i/6)},{\y+sqrt(\x)+2*sin(360*\i/6)}) circle(0.45);
    }
  }
 }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]