# Warning in you code

Tags: tikz-pgf

On this page:

[Neural Network representation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40718/neural-network-representation)

I took neural network drawing but i have an error on that:

```
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}{
    \foreach \j in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}{
        \path[normal arrow,Cyan, draw opacity=0.2] (nx\i) -- (cl1n\j);
    }
}
```

- *cl1n*

  is like not declared or defined can you help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that reproduces this problem.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a full MWE, including `xcolor` option and required TikZ libraries. Does the example work now for you (use LuaLaTeX)?