# Drawing neural network with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a neural network diagram with `tikz`. I found this code online:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
plain/.style={
  draw=none,
  fill=none,
  },
net/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  nodes={
    draw,
    circle,
    inner sep=8.5pt
    },
  nodes in empty cells,
  column sep=0.6cm,
  row sep=-11pt
  },
>=latex
]
\matrix[net] (mat)
{
|[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Input\\layer} & |[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Hidden\\layer} & |[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Output\\layer} \\
& |[plain]| \\
|[plain]| & \\
& |[plain]| \\
|[plain]| & |[plain]| \\
& & \\
|[plain]| & |[plain]| \\
& |[plain]| \\
|[plain]| & \\
& |[plain]| \\
};
\foreach \ai [count=\mi ]in {2,4,...,10}
  \draw[<-] (mat-\ai-1) -- node[above] {I\mi} +(-1cm,0);
\foreach \ai in {2,4,...,10}
{\foreach \aii in {3,6,9}
  \draw[->] (mat-\ai-1) -- (mat-\aii-2);
}
\foreach \ai in {3,6,9}
  \draw[->] (mat-\ai-2) -- (mat-6-3);
\draw[->] (mat-6-3) -- node[above] {O1} +(1cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{ANN diagram for Speed Sign recognition.}
\label{fig_m_3}
\end{figure}
```

It produces the following image:

[image]

It has 5 input nodes but I want to generalize this drawing by having n nodes in each of the layers. So in input layer, number of node shown will be 4 with vertical '...' in middle, the hidden layer would contain 3 nodes with vertical '...' in middle and output would have 2 nodes with vertical '...' in middle. I want to maintain their conical shape. Something like this:

[image]

It is a really bad drawing, sorry about that, one can now imagine how bad I must be with `tikz`. The dots in middle are actually fully filled, in my drawing they are hollow. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40718/neural-network-representation

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here, we a have a festival of `\foreach`:

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  every neuron/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=1cm
  },
  neuron missing/.style={
    draw=none, 
    scale=4,
    text height=0.333cm,
    execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$
  },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, >=stealth]

\foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {1,2,3,missing,4}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try] (input-\m) at (0,2.5-\y) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (hidden-\m) at (2,2-\y*1.25) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (output-\m) at (4,1.5-\y) {};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,2,3,n}
  \draw [<-] (input-\i) -- ++(-1,0)
    node [above, midway] {$I_\l$};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,n}
  \node [above] at (hidden-\i.north) {$H_\l$};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,n}
  \draw [->] (output-\i) -- ++(1,0)
    node [above, midway] {$O_\l$};

\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
    \draw [->] (input-\i) -- (hidden-\j);

\foreach \i in {1,...,2}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
    \draw [->] (hidden-\i) -- (output-\j);

\foreach \l [count=\x from 0] in {Input, Hidden, Ouput}
  \node [align=center, above] at (\x*2,2) {\l \\ layer};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Although it seems unwise to have `n` denote the number of nodes in each layer when they could be different and the arrangement of the diagram suggests they are not.

[image]

Comment: Both the answers are perfect and I learned from both. But I had to choose one. I easily changed this code to my requirements. Thanks.

Comment: And how would one have dots to show that there are many hidden layers?

Comment: Very minor comment: I guess the first `\foreach` does not need the `\l` because it seems not to be used.

Comment: how can you write in the nodes?

Comment: What is the variable '\l' being used for? (it appears in the first foreach inside the tikzpicture environment but I don't see it the following commands)

Comment: I just had a problem with much too big bounding boxes of the missing neurons, which led to a not centered image. You can add after 'scale=4,': 'inner sep=0cm, minimum size=0cm,'

Comment: how to also show the weights on the edges, e.g., `W_{11}` in this figure?

Answer (score 25):

I found this package [neuralnetwork](https://github.com/battlesnake/neural), made by Mark K Cowan, which makes drawing neural networks pretty simple. For example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{neuralnetwork}

\begin{document}
    \begin{neuralnetwork}[height=4]
        \newcommand{\x}[2]{$x_#2$}
        \newcommand{\y}[2]{$\hat{y}_#2$}
        \newcommand{\hfirst}[2]{\small $h^{(1)}_#2$}
        \newcommand{\hsecond}[2]{\small $h^{(2)}_#2$}
        \inputlayer[count=3, bias=true, title=Input\\layer, text=\x]
        \hiddenlayer[count=4, bias=false, title=Hidden\\layer 1, text=\hfirst] \linklayers
        \hiddenlayer[count=3, bias=false, title=Hidden\\layer 2, text=\hsecond] \linklayers
        \outputlayer[count=2, title=Output\\layer, text=\y] \linklayers
    \end{neuralnetwork}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The question really seems to be about the dots, although your code is very elegant.

Comment: Package author here, glad to see it's been useful to people!  You can caption a node with dots (and possibly remove the background colour) to get the desired effect, although I guess this comes 2 years late.

Comment: Why not give an answer @MarkKCowan?

Comment: @Lin I have barely used LaTeX for almost a decade, I think this answer is better than one I'd write nowadays.

Comment: How can I exlude some connections between Hidden Layer $1$ and Hidden Layer  $2$?

Answer (score 9):

This is a solution where a `dot` with fully filled with black circle, whose size is changeable via `minimum size=xx <dimension>`, is defined as a style.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
plain/.style={
  draw=none,
  fill=none,
  },
dot/.style={draw,shape=circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0,fill=black
  },
net/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  nodes={
    draw,
    circle,
    inner sep=8.5pt
    },
  nodes in empty cells,
  column sep=0.6cm,
  row sep=-11pt
  },
>=latex
]
\matrix[net] (mat)
{
|[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Input\\layer} 
          & |[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Hidden\\layer} 
                       & |[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Output\\layer} \\
          & |[plain]|                 \\
|[plain]| &            & |[plain]|    \\
          & |[plain]|  &              \\
|[plain]| & |[dot]|                   \\
          & |[plain]|  & |[dot]|      \\
|[plain]| & |[dot]|    & |[plain]|    \\
|[dot]|   & |[plain]|  & |[dot]|      \\
|[dot]|   & |[dot]|    & |[plain]|    \\
|[dot]|   & |[plain]|  &              \\
|[plain]| &            & |[plain]|    \\
          & |[plain]|                 \\
};
\foreach \ai/\mi in {2/I1,4/I2,6/I3,12/In}
  \draw[<-] (mat-\ai-1) -- node[above] {\mi} +(-1cm,0);
\foreach \ai in {2,4,6,12}
{\foreach \aii/\mii in {3/H1,11/Hn}
  \draw[->] (mat-\ai-1) -- (mat-\aii-2) node[yshift=0.6cm] {\mii};
}
\foreach \ai in {3,11}
{  \draw[->] (mat-\ai-2) -- (mat-4-3);
  \draw[->] (mat-4-3) -- node[above] {O1} +(1cm,0);}
\foreach \ai in {3,11}
{  \draw[->] (mat-\ai-2) -- (mat-10-3);
  \draw[->] (mat-10-3) -- node[above] {On} +(1cm,0);}
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{ANN diagram for Speed Sign recognition.}
\label{fig_m_3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And how would one have dots to show that there are many hidden layers?

Answer (score 9):

This might still be useful to some who would like to easily change the number of layers or nodes without creating new for loops: Using the `listofitems` package, one can define an array with the number of nodes per layer

```
\readlist\Nnod{4,3,2} % number of nodes per layer
% \Nnodlen = length of \Nnod (i.e. total number of layers)
% \Nnod[1] = element (number of nodes) at index 1
\foreachitem \N \in \Nnod{ % loop over layers
  % \N     = current element in this iteration (i.e. number of nodes for this layer)
  % \Ncnt  = index of current layer in this iteration
  \foreach \i [evaluate={\x=\Ncnt; \y=\N/2-\i+0.5;}] in {1,...,\N}{ % loop over nodes
    \draw[mynode] (\x,\y) circle (0.3 cm);
  }
}
```

To add layers, simply add the number of nodes in `\Nnod`. In the full code below, `\Nstr` and `\Cstr` can be used to define different coefficients symbols for the input, hidden and output layers. I left some more general examples on [TikZ.net](https://tikz.net/neural_networks/).

With `\readlist\Nnod{4,3,2}`:

[image: Neural network with 3 layers]

With `\readlist\Nnod{5,4,4,4,3}`:

[image: Neural network with 5 layers]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \ifnumcomp
\usepackage{listofitems} % for \readlist to create arrays

\tikzset{>=latex} % for LaTeX arrow head
\colorlet{myred}{red!80!black}
\colorlet{myblue}{blue!80!black}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!60!black}
\colorlet{mydarkred}{myred!40!black}
\colorlet{mydarkblue}{myblue!40!black}
\colorlet{mydarkgreen}{mygreen!40!black}
\tikzstyle{node}=[very thick,circle,draw=myblue,minimum size=22,inner sep=0.5,outer sep=0.6]
\tikzstyle{connect}=[->,thick,mydarkblue,shorten >=1]
\tikzset{ % node styles, numbered for easy mapping with \nstyle
  node 1/.style={node,mydarkgreen,draw=mygreen,fill=mygreen!25},
  node 2/.style={node,mydarkblue,draw=myblue,fill=myblue!20},
  node 3/.style={node,mydarkred,draw=myred,fill=myred!20},
}
\def\nstyle{int(\lay<\Nnodlen?min(2,\lay):3)} % map layer number onto 1, 2, or 3

\begin{document}


% NEURAL NETWORK
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2.4cm,y=1.2cm]
  \readlist\Nnod{4,3,2} % array of number of nodes per layer
  \readlist\Nstr{n,m,k} % array of string number of nodes per layer
  \readlist\Cstr{x,h^{(\prev)},y} % array of coefficient symbol per layer
  \def\yshift{0.55} % shift last node for dots
  
  % LOOP over LAYERS
  \foreachitem \N \in \Nnod{
    \def\lay{\Ncnt} % alias of index of current layer
    \pgfmathsetmacro\prev{int(\Ncnt-1)} % number of previous layer
    \foreach \i [evaluate={\c=int(\i==\N); \y=\N/2-\i-\c*\yshift;
                 \x=\lay; \n=\nstyle;
                 \index=(\i<\N?int(\i):"\Nstr[\n]");}] in {1,...,\N}{ % loop over nodes
      % NODES
      \node[node \n] (N\lay-\i) at (\x,\y) {$\strut\Cstr[\n]_{\index}$};
      
      % CONNECTIONS
      \ifnumcomp{\lay}{>}{1}{ % connect to previous layer
        \foreach \j in {1,...,\Nnod[\prev]}{ % loop over nodes in previous layer
          \draw[white,line width=1.2,shorten >=1] (N\prev-\j) -- (N\lay-\i);
          \draw[connect] (N\prev-\j) -- (N\lay-\i);
        }
        \ifnum \lay=\Nnodlen
          \draw[connect] (N\lay-\i) --++ (0.5,0); % arrows out
        \fi
      }{
        \draw[connect] (0.5,\y) -- (N\lay-\i); % arrows in
      }
      
    }
    \path (N\lay-\N) --++ (0,1+\yshift) node[midway,scale=1.6] {$\vdots$}; % dots
  }
  
  % LABELS
  \node[above=3,align=center,mydarkgreen] at (N1-1.90) {Input\\[-0.2em]layer};
  \node[above=2,align=center,mydarkblue] at (N2-1.90) {Hidden\\[-0.2em]layers};
  \node[above=3,align=center,mydarkred] at (N\Nnodlen-1.90) {Output\\[-0.2em]layer};
  
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly the graph I would like to make, but I would like somehow to stress the fact that the number of layer can be general. Hence I would like have a fake layer where we would have \ldots. How would that be realizable ?

Answer (score 8):

I know that this is an old question. But I just found this code by Kjell Magne Fauske on [TeXample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/neural-network/) about a neural network and I think it can be helpful to future readers since it's easy to modify.

[image: example]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\layersep{2.5cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
    \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
    \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=red!50];
    \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=blue!50];
    \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

    % Draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,4}
    % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
        \node[input neuron, pin=left:Input \#\y] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,5}
        \path[yshift=0.5cm]
            node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};

    % Draw the output layer node
    \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H-3] (O) {};

    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,4}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,5}
            \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);

    % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
    \foreach \source in {1,...,5}
        \path (H-\source) edge (O);

    % Annotate the layers
    \node[annot,above of=H-1, node distance=1cm] (hl) {Hidden layer};
    \node[annot,left of=hl] {Input layer};
    \node[annot,right of=hl] {Output layer};
\end{tikzpicture}
% End of code
\end{document}
```