# How to draw a neural network (deep GP) in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to type in Latex an image similar to this one.

[image]

Can anybody help?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which parts of the above diagram are proving difficult?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: I tried to replicate what it is explained in this question. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132444/diagram-of-an-artificial-neural-network  However, I cant figure out how to put text inside the figures.

Comment: See also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153957/drawing-neural-network-with-tikz?rq=1) and [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132444/diagram-of-an-artificial-neural-network).

Comment: @user98982 Great, then show us the state of your code.

Comment: [Diagram of an artificial neural network](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132444/diagram-of-an-artificial-neural-network)