# Draw a filled neural network diagram with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a neural network diagram with tikz. 
I want to change the circle color.
e.g. Inputs should be green filled.
I thank you in advance.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, >=latex]
\tikzset{%
 every neuron/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=1cm},
neuron missing/.style={
    draw=none, 
    scale=4,
    text height=0.333cm,
    execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$},
}

\foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {1,2,3,missing,4}
   \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try,green!50] (input-\m) at (0,2.5-\y) {};

 \foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
    \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try,red!50] (output-\m) at (4,1.5-\y) {};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,2,3,n}
  \draw [<-] (input-\i) -- ++(-1,0)
   node [above, midway] {$x_\l$};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,n}
  \draw [->] (output-\i) -- ++(1,0)
   node [above, midway] {$a_\l$};

\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
   \draw [->] (input-\i) -- (output-\j);

\foreach \l [count=\x from 0] in {Eingangs-, Ausgangs-}
  \node [align=center, above] at (\x*4,2) {\l \\ Neuronen};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It produces that.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.  It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Try `\node [every neuron/.try,fill=green, neuron \m/.try,green!50]` in the first `\foreach` loop. But what are you doing here with `every` and `/.try`?

Comment: It doesn't work.  Here is minimal example. It can maybe help you. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153957/drawing-neural-network-with-tikz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been nice if you would have provided the [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153957/drawing-neural-network-with-tikz) to the origin of your code in your question. I marked the changes in the code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, >=latex]
\tikzset{%
 every neuron/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=1cm},
neuron missing/.style={
    draw=none, 
    fill=none, %<- added
    scale=4,
    text height=0.333cm,
    execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$},
}

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,2,3,missing,4} %<- removed "/\l" here 
   \node [fill=green,every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try,green!50] (input-\m) at (0,2.5-\y) {};
% added "fill=green" in the line above

 \foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
    \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try,red!50] (output-\m) at (4,1.5-\y) {};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,2,3,n}
  \draw [<-] (input-\i) -- ++(-1,0)
   node [above, midway] {$x_\l$};

\foreach \l [count=\i] in {1,n}
  \draw [->] (output-\i) -- ++(1,0)
   node [above, midway] {$a_\l$};

\foreach \i in {1,...,4}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,2}
   \draw [->] (input-\i) -- (output-\j);

\foreach \l [count=\x from 0] in {Eingangs-, Ausgangs-}
  \node [align=center, above] at (\x*4,2) {\l \\ Neuronen};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]