# Is it possible to draw a neural network diagram with rectangles?

Tags: diagrams

a post ([Drawing neural network with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153957/192089)) gives a nice solution to draw a neural network diagram.

[image]

Is it possible to draw a neural network diagram with rectangles? something like this

[image]

it seems that `tikz` uses `node` to denote each neuron, how to draw a rectangle to represent the whole layer?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat LOL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,chains,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{% 
    attach arrow/.style={
    decoration={
        markings,
         mark=at position 0 with {\pgfextra{%
         \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpArrowTime}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc arrow/length}/(\pgfdecoratedpathlength)}%
         \xdef\tmpArrowTime{\tmpArrowTime}}},
        mark=at position {#1-3*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@1);},
        mark=at position {#1-2*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@2);},
        mark=at position {#1-1*\tmpArrowTime} with {\coordinate(@3);},
        mark=at position {#1+\tmpArrowTime/2} with {\coordinate(@4);
        \draw[-{Stealth[length=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/arc arrow/length},bend]}] plot[smooth]
         coordinates {(@1) (@2) (@3) (@4)};},
        },
     postaction=decorate,
     },
     attach arrow/.default=0.5,
     arc arrow/.cd,length/.initial=2mm,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,>={Stealth[bend]},
    block/.style={draw, rectangle,minimum height=1.6em,minimum width=9em,
    rotate=90,},decide/.code={\ifnum#1<7
     \tikzset{fill=purple!10,execute at begin node={$\mathsf{3}\times\mathsf{3}$ conv, 64}}
    \else
     \tikzset{fill=green!10,execute at begin node={$\mathsf{3}\times\mathsf{3}$ conv, 128}}
    \fi}]
 \begin{scope}[start chain=A placed {at={(\tikzchaincount*3em,0)}},
    nodes={on chain,block,join= by {thick,->},decide=\tikzchaincount}]
  \path foreach \X in {1,...,6}{node{}}
    node{/2}
    foreach \X in {1,...,7}{node{}};
 \end{scope}
 \foreach \X in {1,...,7}
 {\draw[thick,attach arrow] \ifnum\X=4 [dashed]\fi 
 (-4.5em+\X*6em,0) to[out=90,in=180] 
 (-1.5em+\X*6em,7em) to[out=0,in=90] (1.5em+\X*6em,0);}
 \path (A-1.north) -- ++ (-2em,0) node[anchor=south,rotate=90](pool){pool}
  -- ++ (-4em,0) node[block,anchor=south,fill=orange!10](A-0)
     {$\mathsf{3}\times\mathsf{3}$ conv, 64};
 \draw[thick,->] (A-0) -- (pool);
 \draw[thick,->] (pool) -- (A-1);
 \draw[thick,<-] (A-0) -- ++ (-6em,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user194703 Any idea how to tinker with the graph you've posted like this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/581039/drawing-a-simple-neural-network-flow-chart-with-tikz