# Draw Special/Custom Neural Networks Architecture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, neuralnetwork

I'm currently trying to produce the following picture of a "special neural network architecture" using TeX:
[image]

The first part (before the "big block entitled logic" and ommiting the grey lines) is just a standard picture of a feedforward neural network as addressed by [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153957/drawing-neural-network-with-tikz).
The picture is easy to draw by hand but I have no idea how to tikz or Tex this...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Thanks I've added a few details and have re-drawn my picture also.  I hope its clearer now :)

Comment: where is the "big block entitled logic"

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a graphical interface? You can later export the code and add it to your file.
These are some of the ones I know; I encourage others to add more.

- [TikZiT](https://tikzit.github.io/)
- [LaTeXDraw](https://sourceforge.net/projects/latexdraw/)
- [TikZcd online editor](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!