# Trees from Graph theory in LaTex

Tags: graphics, tikz-trees, graphs

Can someone give me a code how to draw this in LaTex.

[image]

Comment: There are probably quite a few similar trees around, a search for *horizontal tree labels right* led to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185692/horizontal-probability-tree-with-level-labels Edit: there might be better ways doing it though. A quite popular package for drawing trees is `forest`, you could have a look at that as well (via the manual or questions on the site).

Comment: That's not how this site is supposed to work. It is not a LaTeX delivery service. Please attempt something yourself and post a question if you get stuck. There are an enormous number of questions around concerning trees of all kind: Ti*k*Z alone, the `trees` library, the tree layouts of its graph-drawing library, `tikz-qtree`, `qtree`, `forest`, `pstrees` ... Lots of examples. The Ti*k*Z example site offers even more although sometimes the code there is outdated.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17549/probability-tree-diagram-with-tikz?rq=1, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199853/tikz-forest-highlighting-level-background, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193848/making-a-probability-tree-using-tikzpicture-forest etc.